# Does Serializable transactions only lock out other transactionscope statements? or everything?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, transactionscope

In a transaction i have the following, `MyEntities` is my context:

```
TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
options.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;

 using(TransactionScope scope =

      new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))

{
    //Do something to database table MyEntities.Users

}
```

Does making my isolation level serializable, make it so that if anywhere else in my code I have something like this

`MyEntities.Users.First(x=>x.name == "test")`

the line of code will wait until the transaction scope is completely done, or does that line of code need to be surrounded in a `using(TrnasactionScope...` statement in order for it to follow the rules of the transaction isolation level.

Comment: In short: If you are trying to exclusively lock whole table (or multiple tables) serializable transaction will not do that by itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isolation-level *by itself* does nothing; what matters is what happens when you start querying data. In particular, you start leaving read-locks all over the place, and key-range locks. If another query hits one of those locks and is *reading*, then that's fine: read-locks are usually compatible. The isolation-level of the other SPID also matters, obviously - a read-uncommitted SPID won't care about your ongoing operation, where-as higher isolations will.

What starts getting more complex is when one of the SPIDs starts *writing* data; that can lead to deadlocks if multiple SPIDs already have read-locks on that same data.

But no: a transaction-scope does not block *everything* else, especially if they are only reading. For what it *does* do... that is complex, and can only really be analysed on a case-by-case basis.